# How to make Qtextedit text and non-selectable?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Is there a PyQt `QTextEdit` method that disables selecting/highlighting of and/or right-clicking on displayed text? Or at least disables clipboard functions such as copy? Thanks.

To clarify none-duplicity of this question, I'm talking about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpVlE.jpg). I want none of that highlight thing when trying to click and drag across part of the displayed text.

Comment: I'm not looking to make the text just read-only. I want to disable the highlighting feature, which is still present after calling `setReadonly(True)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with this

```
#QTextEdit.setTextInteractionFlags (self, Qt.TextInteractionFlags flags)
#QTextEdit.setText (self, QString text)

textEdit.setTextInteractionFlags (QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)    
textEdit.setText ('How to make Qtextedit text and non-selectable?')
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
txt_field.setDisabled(True)
```

Then it disables selecting or highlighting of displayed text.

Comment: Thanks. It does the job but it changes the text color to gray, which I don't intend.